# Tooltips show from windows underneath focused window

Tags: finder

[Mac OS 10.13.3, GTK+3 (HomeBrew), XQuartz 2.7.11]

I'm finding that in various cases, tooltips pop up that relate to windows I have lower in my view stack.  For example, I have Finder open, and Komodo Editor 10/11 or Glade 3.20.2 in the background, when I happen to move the mouse over something that these apps present tooltips for, the tooltip is shown even though they actual object is not visible (as it's behind Finder) and Finder has focus.

I believe this has something to do with GTK+3 but I'm not certain.

Anyone else having this problem and/or know how to fix it?

(I would like to use tags:  GTK+3 and Tooltip but neither exist.)

Comment: Happened once to me. Restarted. Never seen it again.

Comment: I've had this problem for a long time now, and restarting hasn't fixed it for me. :(

Comment: I have what sounds like the same problem, but I'm not running anything related to gtk. I just have a lot of Safari windows open, and keep seeing tooltips from Safari windows behind the current one. (Did you ever solve this?)

Comment: I've had the same problem for months now, restarting doesn't help, updating doesn't help. I don't think it can be about GTK because I only installed that recently, long after the problem started? I do have a lot of Safari windows open.